# XP SP2 hangs on logo screen, running chkdsk /p /r now hanging

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, chkdsk

I have a windows xp sp 2 on a toshiba laptop, Ive been using it for many years.

The other day it hung on the windows logo and would only start in safemode.

I did a best configuration, restore, then a disk check on next startup by right clicking on the C drive.

The next time it started I got a blinking cursor and could only get into the Repair Console using my OS CD and it no longer starts in safemode.

From the repair console I replaced the hal.dll file (as I had this error) and no joy, then I did a bootcfg etc. no luck, then I did a chkdisk /p and it said no need for scan, disc is fine, so I forced a chkdsk /p /r and its been running about 6 hours, was moving progressively but is now stuck at 74%...

My question is how long should I let it run??? and is the only way out holding down the power key, and if I do that will my laptop be toast?

Thanks and regards,
Roisin

Comment: IMO, it is time to upgrade. I would recommend not using Windows XP anymore.  Especially if it is connected to the Internet.

Comment: First of all I need to recover my information, I am looking for a solution to my current situation...

Comment: Slave that hard drive to a new machine that isn't running Windows XP.  Then copy over your information.

Comment: My question was "My question is how long should I let it run??? and is the only way out holding down the power key, and if I do that will my laptop be toast?"

Comment: The fact it's stuck indicates a hardware failure

Comment: Thank you, should I just end it with the power button or wait longer??? overnight maybe???

Answer (score 0):

By using `chkdsk /p /r`, you are instructing it to perform an extensive check and correct any errors while recovering any readable information.  Which means it is going to check the whole hard drive.

The length of time required to run `chkdsk` depends on the speed and size of the drive.

If it is stuck likely you have a hard drive issue.  You are not going to harm it further by forcing it to shut down.  So, go for it, that is your only option anyway.

You say you have been using it for years.  So, I would recommend slaving the drive to a working machine and copying any information off of it that you don't want to lose.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I bought a disc enclosure and have connected it to another working laptop with the usb connection. Now to figure out how to slave the disc, all suggestions at this point are very welcome!